# Set up different actiavtion functions for different layers using "neuralnet" package

Tags: r, neural-network, layer, relu

Ciao,
I am working to neuralnet in R.
I used to program this kind of stuff using Keras in python so I would expect to be able to set up different activation functions for different layers.

Let me explain. Suppose I want to build a neural net with 2 hidden layers (say with 5 and 4 neurons) and an output between -1 and 1.

I would like to set up *RELU* or *softplus* in the hidden layers and *tanh* in the output layer.

The issue here is that *neuralnet* package lets me choose only one activation function via the argument *act.fun*:

```
> nn <- neuralnet(data = data, hidden = c(5, 4), act.fun =tanh)
```

I tried by setting the act.fun argument as **c(softplus, softplus, tanh)** but of course I get an error because the *neuralnet* function expects only one function for that argument.

Do you know how I can set up the neuralnet in this way? On the internet I can only find very basic linear neural net built with this package. If it would be not possible this mean that this package is almost useless because it would be able to build only "linear models" (??!)

Thanks a lot,
ciao

Comment: Maybe it's possible? but that package is not a framework equivalent to Keras. If you've already used Keras in Python and are currently working in R, [you can use Keras from R](https://keras.rstudio.com/). It uses reticulate to go through Python anyway, though, so if you're already comfortable with that interface, you might as well stick with it unless this is part of a larger project in R.

Comment: @alistaire Thsx for your comment. Unfortunately I cannot install Keras on the current version I am using and I cannot upgrade it.

Answer (score 1):

ReLu was added in neuralnet 1.44.4 (not on CRAN yet, could use `devtools::install_github("bips-hb/neuralnet")`). In this version it's also possible to change the output activation function separately (`output.act.fct`). However, different activations for the hidden layers is not yet possible. 
See also here: https://github.com/bips-hb/neuralnet/issues/18.

> On the internet I can only find very basic linear neural net built with this package. If it would be not possible this mean that this package is almost useless because it would be able to build only "linear models" (??!)

No, not only linear models. But note that the package is from the pre-deep learning era (2008) and not made for deep networks. I would also recommend keras (the R package is great) here.